# Creating a class with Selenium in Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am just trying to create a class for bot testing with Selenium. Here's the layout of my project:

```
Project/
  booking/
    __init__.py
    booking.py
    constants.py
run.py
```

Run.py is where I am trying to run the code, outside of the booking folder, but inside of the Project folder, run.py:

```
from booking.booking import Booking


inst = Booking()
inst.land_first_page()
```

In my booking.py code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import booking.constants as const


    class Booking(webdriver.Chrome): 
        def __init__(self, driver_path=r"C:/Selenium Drivers/chromedriver.exe"): 
            self.driver_path = driver_path
            os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
            super(Booking, self).__init__()
    
        def land_first_page(self):
            self.get(const.BASE_URL)
```

I keep getting the error 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH, but I thought
this line would take care of that:

```
os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where are you creating object of ChromeDriver ?

Comment: In a python file I named run outside of the booking folder, but inside of the project folder. I made an edit to the question to reflect

Comment: I would need to see Run.py file content to provide you any input

Comment: Just added my run.py to the question ! Nothing special, all I'm doing is testing to see I can connect to the page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
```

try using

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + self.driver_path
```

or

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + driver_path
```